# Android Design Support Library. Toolbar animation

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-support-design

In my application I want to implement Quick return pattern for toolbar with tabs like in Google Play application.

Here is my activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
            style="@style/AppTabStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
            style="@style/TabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have Fragments that contain RecyclerViews in ViewPager. So, everything works fine, Toolbar hides, when RecyclerView scrolls to bottom and shows otherwise. But if I scroll RecyclerView a little, it's possible to display Toolbar in a wrong state.

Initial state:
[image: Initial state]

Wrong state:
[image: Wrong state]

I want toolbar animation like in google play. Is it possible using design support library? Does anybody have great `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` for such cases?